# How to recreate MenuItem ItemTapped and Command with a Button

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a model called "ListItem", and I'm printing a list of them. I used to just use a ListView, but I wanted to print them horizontally, so I created a custom WrapLayout.

The ListView had simple ways to perform actions when the items were tapped or long-pressed. When a MenuItem was tapped, `PutBack` was called, and the ListItem was passed through as parameters. When a MenuItem was long-pressed, a button reading "delete" appeared in the toolbar, and when that was tapped, `DeleteListItem` was called and the ListItem was passed through as parameters.

**Old Xaml:**

```
<ListView x:Name="inactiveList" ItemTapped="PutBack" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}">
                <TextCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ListPage}, Path=DeleteListItem}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="delete" />
                </TextCell.ContextActions>
            </TextCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I'm having trouble recreating this functionality with the buttons generated by my custom WrapLayout. Is this possible to do? I tried adding a `Clicked` property to the buttons, but VS tells me I can only set Clicked with `+=` or `-=`, which doesn't make any sense to me.

**New Xaml:**

```
<local:WrapLayout x:Name="inactiveList" Spacing="5" />
```

**New Code-Behind:**

```
namespace Myapp
{
  public partial class ListPage
  {
    public Command DeleteListItem { get; set; }

    public ListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<ListItem> inactiveItems =
            new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                App.ListItemRepo.GetInactiveListItems());
        inactiveList.ItemsSource = inactiveItems;


        DeleteListItem = new Command(async (parameter) => {
            ListItem item = (ListItem)parameter as ListItem;
            App.ListItemRepo.DeleteListItemAsync(item);

            ObservableCollection<ListItem> deleteInactiveItems =
                new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                    await App.ListItemRepo.GetInactiveListItemsAsync());
            inactiveList.ItemsSource = deleteInactiveItems;
        });
    }


    public async void PutBack(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedListItem = e.Item as ListItem;

        await App.ListItemRepo.SetListItemActive(selectedListItem);

        ObservableCollection<ListItem> inactiveItems =
            new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                await App.ListItemRepo.GetInactiveListItemsAsync());
        inactiveList.ItemsSource = inactiveItems;
    }
  }

  public class WrapLayout : Layout<View>
  {

    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<ListItem>)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create
        (
            "ItemsSource",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<ListItem>),
            typeof(WrapLayout),
            propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) => ((WrapLayout)bindable).AddViews()
        );

    // THIS IS WHERE THE BUTTONS ARE SET
    void AddViews()
    {
        Children.Clear();
        foreach (ListItem s in ItemsSource)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = s.Name;
            Children.Add(button);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SpacingProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create
        (
            "Spacing",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(WrapLayout),
            10.0,
            propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) => ((WrapLayout)bindable).OnSizeChanged()
        );

    public double Spacing
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(SpacingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SpacingProperty, value); }
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged()
    {
        this.ForceLayout();
    }

    protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        if (WidthRequest > 0)
            widthConstraint = Math.Min(widthConstraint, WidthRequest);
        if (HeightRequest > 0)
            heightConstraint = Math.Min(heightConstraint, HeightRequest);

        double internalWidth = double.IsPositiveInfinity(widthConstraint) ? double.PositiveInfinity : Math.Max(0, widthConstraint);
        double internalHeight = double.IsPositiveInfinity(heightConstraint) ? double.PositiveInfinity : Math.Max(0, heightConstraint);

        return DoHorizontalMeasure(internalWidth, internalHeight);
    }

    private SizeRequest DoHorizontalMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        int rowCount = 1;

        double width = 0;
        double height = 0;
        double minWidth = 0;
        double minHeight = 0;
        double widthUsed = 0;

        foreach (var item in Children)
        {
            var size = item.Measure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);

            height = Math.Max(height, size.Request.Height);

            var newWidth = width + size.Request.Width + Spacing;
            if (newWidth > widthConstraint)
            {
                rowCount++;
                widthUsed = Math.Max(width, widthUsed);
                width = size.Request.Width;
            }
            else
                width = newWidth;

            minHeight = Math.Max(minHeight, size.Minimum.Height);
            minWidth = Math.Max(minWidth, size.Minimum.Width);
        }

        if (rowCount > 1)
        {
            width = Math.Max(width, widthUsed);
            height = (height + Spacing) * rowCount - Spacing; // via MitchMilam 
        }

        return new SizeRequest(new Size(width, height), new Size(minWidth, minHeight));
    }

    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        double rowHeight = 0;
        double yPos = y, xPos = x;

        foreach (var child in Children.Where(c => c.IsVisible))
        {
            var request = child.Measure(width, height);

            double childWidth = request.Request.Width;
            double childHeight = request.Request.Height;
            rowHeight = Math.Max(rowHeight, childHeight);

            if (xPos + childWidth > width)
            {
                xPos = x;
                yPos += rowHeight + Spacing;
                rowHeight = 0;
            }

            var region = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, childWidth, childHeight);
            LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(child, region);
            xPos += region.Width + Spacing;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If it is just the delete action that you want to recreate, then wouldn't you just add a RoutedEventHandler delegate as VS suggests and give it a function to call? No need for commands I would think...

Comment: I want to recreate both the PutBack and the DeleteListItem actions.